# JVM crashes while authenticating pub/sub

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, segmentation-fault, jvm, google-cloud-pubsub

I use GCP [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/create-topic-client-libraries) to implement pub/sub model in my spring-boot application. For authenticating i'm using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS path env variable. It works fine with other versions of JDK/JRE, But it fails with segmentation Error with below mentioned jdk/jre

Environment details

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.60.0.22-SA-linux-musl-x64) (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.60.0.22-SA-linux-musl-x64) (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

Log:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000003fd6, pid=1, tid=0x00007f99a14fcb38 
# 
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.60.0.22-SA-linux-musl-x64) (8.0_322-b06) (build 1.8.0_322-b06) 
# 
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.322-b06 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops) 
# Problematic frame: 
# C 0x0000000000003fd6 
# 
# Core dump written. Default location: //core or core.1 
# 
# An error report file with more information is saved as: 
# /tmp/hs_err_pid1.log 
# 
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: 
# http://www.azul.com/support/


Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+328
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+92
j  java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
j  java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+5
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 2066  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad99bdf7 [0x00007f5cad99bd80+0x77]
J 2065 C1 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (104 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad9a2a8c [0x00007f5cad9a1900+0x118c]
J 1974 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad961784 [0x00007f5cad961680+0x104]
J 2084 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad9a3e8c [0x00007f5cad9a3aa0+0x3ec]
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+53
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1349  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad764f4f [0x00007f5cad764f00+0x4f]
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+10
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+15
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V+359
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.loadNativeLibrary()V+60
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.<clinit>()V+76
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll.<clinit>()V+28
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 993  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad6995fa [0x00007f5cad699580+0x7a]
J 1952 C1 java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (15 bytes) @ 0x00007f5cad948d4c [0x00007f5cad948ba0+0x1ac]
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.isEpollAvailable()Z+3
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>()V+144
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<clinit>()V+16
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lio/grpc/netty/shaded/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder;+2
j  io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lio/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder;+3
j  io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lio/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder;+5
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel()Lio/grpc/ManagedChannel;+285
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$$Lambda$596.createSingleChannel()Lio/grpc/ManagedChannel;+4
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.<init>(Lcom/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelPoolSettings;Lcom/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelFactory;Ljava/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService;)V+71
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(Lcom/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelPoolSettings;Lcom/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelFactory;)Lcom/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelPool;+9
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel()Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/TransportChannel;+10
j  com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel()Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/TransportChannel;+35
j  com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/StubSettings;)Lcom/google/api/gax/rpc/ClientContext;+179
j  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(Lcom/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/stub/SubscriberStubSettings;)Lcom/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/stub/GrpcSubscriberStub;+6
j  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.doStart()V+16
j  com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStart()V+4
j  com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAsync()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/Service;+33
j  com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.startAsync()Lcom/google/api/core/ApiService;+4
j  com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.startAsync()Lcom/google/api/core/ApiService;+1
```

Dependencies:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>25.1.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
   <dependencies>
```

And also i wanted to know is there any other way to authenticate other than using path env variable? Can I use `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:{location}` with GCP client libraries, instead of env variable?

Comment: You can examine the generated file to get some details but it seems this is a problem with the underlying google library. Maybe similar to this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3536

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Juraj Martinka, it was problem with underlying google library `io.grpc.netty.shaded`. It seems Netty does not support Alpine since Netty depends on glibc but Alpine does not have it, it has musl libc instead.

The issue disappears if you disable Netty's native support
or if you use an image that has glibc, e.g.:

`azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11-jre`: Alpine-based, no glibc -> does not work
`azul/zulu-openjdk:11`: Ubuntu-based, has glibc -> works

Using `-Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.transport.noNative=true` avoids the segfault

example:

```
java -jar -Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.transport.noNative=true app.jar
```

The other workaround is, using `grpc-netty` instead of `grpc-netty-shaded`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Reference Links: [Link 1](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/6425), [Link 2](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2776)